# A 16:9, full HD, portrait oriented display?

Tags: display, portrait

when I program I like to see as much code as possible in my editor. Latest high res displays are great to get a lot of lines in, but wouldn't it be even *better* if I could run a 1920x1080 dispay in portrait mode?

Anybody know if full HD, portrait-orientable displays exist out there? Looking for 20-22 inch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using 2 of thoses [EV2303W](http://www.eizo.com/global/products/flexscan/ev2303w/index.html) ! They aren't cheap, but you won't regret to invest into a high end display ! You can put them in portrait mode !

Comment: Quality Kami, that is **EXACTLY** what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [NEC2490WUXI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MT5J7I) should offer pivot and has an excellent view.  Otherwise have a look at this list: http://www.pchardwarehelp.com/guides/s-ips-lcd-list.php

Answer (score 0):

Dell do these kinds of monitors too. Here is an [example](http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1&sku=151077) after a quick search. It's not full HD but I'm sure with some longer searching you will find one that is.

[image]

[image]